# What happen when event is unsubscribe before subscribe it in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

What exactly happen when event is unsubscribe before subscribe it.
At code level it will not throw any exception but exactly what kind of core logic is their which handle this situation.

```
try
{
    // function (which may throw exception)
    doWork();

    // Subscribe event
    _test.MyEvent += MyEventHandler;

    // other code
}
catch (Exception)
{
     // do error handling
}
finally
{
     // Unsubscribe event
    test.MyEvent -= MyEventHandler;
}
```

If doWork() function throws the exception then in finally event unsubscription will takes place. Regarding this what will be the best solution to handle this situation.

Is it better to handle this situation with the help of bool variable to make judgement before un-subscription.

Or

It is OK to unsubscribe event without checking as it will not throw any exception.

Comment: Events are processed as part of the Windows Timer Tick Event handler which has a list of events to be processed.  When a new event occurs it is put on a list of events to process.  Then windows looks at the list of events to process and finds the first process that is registered for an event.  If nobody is registered for the event windows remove the event from the list and continues so nothing happens.  So your answer is NOTHING.

Comment: It means event is not subscribe so it will not added to the event list, so when try to unsubscribe it, it is not present  in event list so it will skip. So it is not a harmful operation.

Comment: No.  If you have a timer and the timer is still running it is putting items on the queue.  Unsubscribe just stops calling the event handler because the registering is moving the timer event to the event handler.

Comment: @jdweng there is nothing specific to Windows, timers, or queues here. An event is just a way of adding/removing delegates. Usually they are placed on a list, which is then called by methods inside the class that exposes the event. All of this is synchronous and has nothing to do with queues, timers, etc.

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker : You are wrong. You do no understand the relationships what is happening in windows and what is happening in the Net Code.

Comment: @jdweng C# runs on Linux and Mac, not just Windows. And events can be (and frequently are) used in situations within the app code, having nothing to do with the external OS. An event is just a kind of callback. It's a formal way for a class to say "pass me a delegate, and I'll call it at some later time". It has nothing intrinsic to do with the OS, timers or queues.

Comment: Events on a operating system are events.  Not stopping the event is different from removing the registering of the event.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the event is implemented. In C# we can declare an event with custom [add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/add) and [remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/remove) logic. The implementer of `add` can store the supplied delegate however they wish.

They could also in theory `throw` from inside `remove` if they think this will help flag up misuse of their class. But this would be surprising behaviour in most cases, because (as you've observed) `-=` on an event is usually tolerant of misuse.

The whole point of custom accessors is to change the usual behaviour, but the principle of least surprise is a good thing to follow.